# WooCommerce Price

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I realize this should be simple for most coders but I am not a coder!

I want to display product price including Currency symbol somewhere on my page/text.

I have done this before but have totally forgotten how to do it! I have copied the code below but am unsure where to place it, also do I replace post_id with my product ID? any help from you guys appreciated

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```

Comment: Depending on the place, there might hooks to show this. Need information on exactly where you are trying to show this

Comment: Thanks for your comment.... I was planning on using a module Raw Html or create a Shortcode

Comment: Where will you be adding the shortcode ? Product page or shop page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can display the products with prices anywhere in your site using this code

```
<?php

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'product_cat' => 'occasions', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    
                            <div class="occasion_block">
                                <div class="occsn_img">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" />'; ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="occsn_cont">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class=""h4_span><?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?> </span></a>
                                   
                                    <div class="occsn_fetr">
                                        
                                        <?php if($product->is_on_sale()){?>
                                       <span class="h5_span"><i><?php  echo '&euro;'. $product->get_regular_price();?></i><b><?php echo '&euro;'.$product->get_sale_price();?></b></span>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                              <?php
       endwhile;
         wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

`'product_cat'` => is what your product category should be shown or else remove that if you need to display all the products

`<?php  echo '&euro;'. $product->get_regular_price();?>` is used to display the products price and you can also change the price symbol as per your need.

Comment: Its almost like it is blocking any code from showing... Whether I place via shortcode or raw html

Comment: you need add this code where you want to display the products . I have shown you the example code for integrating in HTML to display the all the product in the category of occassions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply by.

```
<?php echo $_product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

where `$_product` is `wc_get_product( $product_id )`.

This ensures that it is compatible for future updates of woocommerce and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function for your requirement.

```
function show_product_price($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 
        'id' => null 
    ), $atts, 'woo_product_price' ); 
  
    if ( empty( $atts[ 'id' ] ) ) { 
        return ''; 
    } 
  
    $product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] ); 
  
    if ( ! $product ) { 
        return ''; 
    } 
  
    return $product->get_price_html(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_product_price', 'show_product_price');
```

So this is a shortcode. You can add `[woo_product_price id="your_product_id"]` to show the price of a particular product in any page. All you have to do is to add the above mentioned shortcode to the page and provide an ID.

This shortcode shows price of product including the currency. As an advantage, if the product is on sale, the sale price will also be shown.

See the image[image: here] to get an idea on how it look.